# How to prevent pandoc from converting align environment to aligned environment?

Tags: align, environments, pandoc, html

My LaTeX code in `foo.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{Demo}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
1 + 0 & = 1, \label{eq1} \\
1 + 1 & = 2. \label{eq2}
\end{align}

Equation \( \eqref{eq1} \) and \( \eqref{eq2} \) describe eternal
truths.

\end{document}
```

My HTML template file `template.html` to feed to `pandoc`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>$title$</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script>window.MathJax = {tex: {tags: 'ams'}}</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
$body$
</body>
</html>
```

My Pandoc command:

```sh
pandoc foo.tex --template=template --standalone --mathjax -o foo.html
```

How the output file `foo.html` looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script>window.MathJax = {tex: {tags: 'ams'}}</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p><span class="math display">\[\begin{aligned}
1 + 0 &amp; = 1, \label{eq1} \\
1 + 1 &amp; = 2. \label{eq2}\end{aligned}\]</span></p>
<p>Equation <span class="math inline">\(\eqref{eq1}\)</span> and <span class="math inline">\(\eqref{eq2}\)</span> desc[![enter image description here][1]][1]ribe eternal truths.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

The issue here is that `pandoc` has changed my `align` environment to `aligned` environments, so I don't get equation numbering anymore.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to tell `pandoc` to stop messing with the `align` environment and changing them to `aligned` environment? Is there a way to keep them intact?
2. If it is not possible to tell `pandoc` to stop messing with the `align` environment, how can I resolve this issue and get equation numbering to work?

Comment: I dont think the issue is with changing the environment (that might even be correct) but I woud guess that you have to use a filter to get references right. Have you tryed that? Otherwise, you might be better off to ask this question on `pandoc-discuss` mailing list.

Comment: Why `\eqref` in math mode?

Comment: @egreg That is the only way I found to prevent Pandoc from processing the `\eqref` command. If I put it in math mode, it remains intact for MathJax to process it.

Comment: This is surely something Pandoc should take care of.

Comment: @egreg I found that if I let Pandoc take care of `\eqref` I get unsatisfactory results, that is, if I do not put `\eqref` in math mode, then Pandoc processes it and produces this result: https://jsfiddle.net/9ryqfau5/ . You can see here that equation references have been rendered as `[eq1]` and `[eq2]` in the output. However, I want them to be rendered as `(1)` and `(2)` like AMS numbering does. That is why I am trying to get MathJax to render the `\eqref` commands.

Comment: @LoneLearner I'm not expert in Pandoc. But it *should* have some *easy* settings in order to allow users to get the result *they* want, not what Pandoc developers like. By the way, I don't think that MathJax knows anything about `\ref` or `\eqref` (which is a wrapper around the former).

Comment: See https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/7968#issuecomment-1069379492 for a workaround.